# Get data copied by a function

Tags: postgresql, function, transactions, common-table-expression

I have a quite complicated data structure that lies in several tables. I have a function that makes a copy of that structure. I want to make a copy and get newly created data in a single query like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    main_table
    JOIN other_table
    ON (main_table.id = other_table.main_id)
WHERE
    main_table.id = make_copy(old_id);
```

The copy is successfully created, but is not returned by the above query. I guess it is not yet visible for the outer query or somehow *committed*.

I have also tried to use `WITH ... SELECT ...` but with no success...

The function `make_copy(id)` is declared as `VOLATILE` because it modifies the database, and multiple calls with the same parameter will create multiple copies.

Possible solution could be that `make_copy(id)` function would return the whole new data structure (`SELECT * FROM make_copy(old_id)`) but it would require many aliasing (many tables have `id` or `name` column). Also I would end up with many places to build (read) that data structure.

How can I call that function and use its result (and all side effects) in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible without splitting it into two queries.

CTE can't help you - [`Data-Modifying Statements in WITH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) (See there example with updating table inside of the cte):

> ...The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each
>   other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
>   statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually
>   happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same
>   snapshot (see Chapter 13), so they cannot “see” one another's effects
>   on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the
>   unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that
>   RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between
>   different WITH sub-statements and the main query...

And I guess you cannot do this with function either - [`Function Volatility Categories`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/xfunc-volatility.html):

> For functions written in SQL or in any of the standard procedural
>   languages, there is a second important property determined by the
>   volatility category, namely the visibility of any data changes that
>   have been made by the SQL command that is calling the function. A
>   VOLATILE function will see such changes, a STABLE or IMMUTABLE
>   function will not. ... VOLATILE functions obtain a fresh snapshot at
>   the start of each query they execute.